# VBA: Would like to extract certain month data with certain year into the corresponding worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code to create the new sheets with different years (2017, 2016, 2015...). But I still need to extract the data from "Data" sheet for certain month into corresponding "Year" sheet

My data will like, where the Date is in DMYYYY format. 
Date Record

2/1/1997 XXX -> goes to "1997"

23/12//2017 xxxx -> goes to "2017"

Code:

```
Sub Select_Month_Year_Data()

    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim wsWithSheetNames As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

    Worksheets("Ref").Select
    Set wsWithSheetNames = ActiveSheet
    Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("A2:A32")

        With wbToAddSheetsTo

            .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
            End If

            On Error GoTo 0

       End With

   Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you written any code to extract the data? Kindly provide that as well.

Comment: Sidenote: You really should try to avoid using 'ActiveSheet'. It makes it hard to read what your code is doing on which sheet, and (becasuse of this?) is often a source for errors. Instead, refer to sheets using their names or numbers.